# Typescript file with bang operator won't build even though tsc version is high enough

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular 4 project with this file

```
class DemoClass {
    description!: string;
}
```

If I build it with

```
ng build
```

from the project root I get

> ERROR in src/app/client/medisoft-client.ts(3,16): error TS1005: '='
>   expected. src/app/client/medisoft-client.ts(3,17): error TS1109:
>   Expression expected.

removing the bang operator resolves this so it's definitely that which is the problem. The error seems like the version of type script isn't high enough but if I run

```
tsc --version
```

I get

> Version 3.3.4000

which is high enough to support the bang operator. Moverover if I go to the directory with the file in and just transpile that one file i.e.

```
tsc --out test.js test.ts
```

then it build fine and I get the js output

So it looks like angular is using an older version of typescript but I'm stumped about where to look now to resolve this

Package.json file is

```
{   "name": "project-name",   "version": "0.0.0",   "license": "MIT",  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng build --base-href /Angular --deploy-url /Angular/",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"   },   "private": true,   "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"   },   "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"   } }
```

Comment: please share your package json file

Comment: @TheParam - done. OK it's saying 2.9.2 which should be high enough shouldn't it. Why does tsc --version give me another version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Angular project typescript version is lower than your global version. so you need to install the updated version in your angular project like below

```
npm install typescript@3.3.4000 --save-dev
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks -- tried this. Getting npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for typescript@3.3.4. npm install typescript@latest --save-dev will run though

Comment: Thanks - angular tells me this @angular/compiler-cli@5.2.3 requires typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.7.0' but 3.3.4000 was found instead. and it fails to buidl now for missing module reasons - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\XXX\Scratch\Tim\Angular\va-dilate\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css'. I guess I need to update the cli as well

Comment: yes you also need to update the angular-cli version as well

Comment: ha - node needs updating as well now . The entire pack of cards needs it

Comment: OK -done. It works so thank you for that. Still getting the warning  npm install typescript@">=2.4.2 <2.7" but the code that i've imported is 2.7 so that's for me to think about and sort out. Anyway - thanks